# Bitcoin-Qt [11690]

Tags: bitcoin-core, nodes, mac

I found this on my mac computer what is the meaning of this can you pls hep me to understand  I am new to this;

```
Process:               Bitcoin-Qt [11690]
Path:                  /Applications/Bitcoin-Qt.app/Contents/MacOS/Bitcoin-Qt
Identifier:            Bitcoin-Qt
Version:               0.17.1 (0.17.1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Bitcoin-Qt [11690]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2019-03-19 15:05:08.490 +0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.3 (18D109)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        03A66689-DA11-7464-D9A3-39528597A7F6

Sleep/Wake UUID:       BDBB57FB-33EB-47A7-A932-49A27856909C

Time Awake Since Boot: 290000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       50000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00004934d67bb3c0
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [11690]

VM Regions Near 0x4934d67bb3c0:
    mapped file            0000000180f6c000-00000001825a0000 [ 22.2M] r--/rwx SM=COW  Object_id=eba21991
--> 
    MALLOC_NANO            0000600000000000-0000600078000000 [  1.9G] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff594d08bf objc_retain + 31
1   com.apple.coreservices.SharedFileList   0x00007fff2ecc3f18 -[SFLLoginItemList removeItem:error:] + 35
2   com.apple.coreservices.SharedFileList   0x00007fff2ecca3c7 LSSharedFileListItemRemove + 127
3   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x0000000108f4a4d7 0x108f0b000 + 259287
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About all one can tell from this log message is that the bitcoin-qt application crashed.  It doesn't contain details as to why.

One possible cause is that the blockchain files are corrupt, which could happen because of a previous crash or if the computer is turned off without closing the app properly.  You could fix this by reinstalling  the application (but make sure to save a copy of your `wallet.dat` file or you will lose all your coins).

It could also be a bug in the application.  If you can reproduce the crash, you can report it at https://bitcoin.org/en/bitcoin-core/contribute/issues

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. I appreciate.